# mysql join only return one result from the join

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I have the following query,

```
SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, 
                    `candidates`.`first_name`, 
                    `candidates`.`surname`, 
                    `candidates`.`DOB`, 
                    `candidates`.`gender`, 
                    `candidates`.`talent`, 
                    `candidates`.`location`, 
                    `candidates`.`availability`,
                     DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) as `age`,
                    `candidate_assets`.`url`, 
                    `candidate_assets`.`asset_size`
            FROM `candidates`
            LEFT JOIN `candidate_assets` ON `candidate_assets`.`candidates_candidate_id` = `candidates`.`candidate_id`
            WHERE `candidates`.`availability` = 'yes'";
```

The query is currently returning multiple rows from the joined table is possible to return only one result per join?

Comment: You can add the LIMIT 1 clause to the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Try to use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, e.g. -

```
SELECT
  c.`candidate_id`, 
  c.`first_name`, 
  c.`surname`, 
  c.`DOB`, 
  c.`gender`, 
  c.`talent`, 
  c.`location`, 
  c.`availability`,
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(c.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(c.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) as `age`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ca.`url`) `url`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ca.`asset_size`) `asset_size`
FROM `candidates` c
LEFT JOIN `candidate_assets` ca ON ca.`candidates_candidate_id` = c.`candidate_id`
WHERE c.`availability` = 'yes'
GROUP BY c.candidate_id
```